# How to implement dynamic filters (linked select box ) with Sonata?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to implement some dynamic filters with Sonata. And I pull my hair.

In fact, I have three objects (Engine > Motor > Sensor).

```
class Engine {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Motor, mappedBy=engine)
     */
    private $motors;
}

class Motor {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Sensor, mappedBy=motor)
     */
    private $sensors;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Engine, inversedBy=motors)
     */
    private $engine;
}

class Sensor {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Motor, inversedBy=sensors)
     */
    private $motor;
}
```

This code is just to have an idea of the model.

In admin part, I would like to filter sensor by engine and by motor. So when I choose engine, I would like motor's filter change automatically.

After some research, my research leads me to the callbacks. But I never used it and documentation about it is very small. So if somebody could help me.

Here is my code for the admin side:

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;

class SensorAdmin extends Admin {

    /**
     * @param DatagridMapper $prmDatagridMapper
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $prmDatagridMapper)
    {
        $prmDatagridMapper
            ->add("motor.engine", null, array("label" => "Engine"))
            ->add('motor', null, array(
                "callback" => array($this, "callbackMotorFilter")
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function callbackMotorFilter ($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value)
    {
        if (!$value) {
            return;
        }

        $queryBuilder->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.motor', $alias), 'm');
        $queryBuilder->leftJoin("m.engine", "e");
        $queryBuilder->andWhere('e.id = :engine_id');
        $queryBuilder->setParameter('engine_id', $value['value']);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd better use any kind of API here. Sending tons of entities to the front-end is not a good idea. Selecting from a thousands entities could hang the browser.

For example you could use any kind of jQuery autocomplete inputs with simple JSON API.

I've implemented one a long time ago.

Form type
https://github.com/scaytrase/form-extensions/blob/master/src/ScayTrase/Forms/ExtensionsBundle/Form/Type/EntityAutocompleteType.php

jQuery plugin
https://github.com/scaytrase/form-extensions/blob/master/src/ScayTrase/Forms/ExtensionsBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.entity_autocomplete.js

Twig template
https://github.com/scaytrase/form-extensions/blob/master/src/ScayTrase/Forms/ExtensionsBundle/Resources/views/Form/entity_autocomplete.html.twig

Not sure it is compatible with latest 3.0 Forms, but modification should be easy

Comment: So, finally, problem resolves by new version. Thanks a lot